# Modally presented view controller dismisses by itself on touching the view in the upper side of the screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller which has a table view and in the didSelectRowAt indexPath I instantiate the destination view controller, embed it into a navigation controller and present it... here is some code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let destVC = DetailVC(frame: self.view.frame)
        //passing data to the destVC ...       
        destVC.modalTransitionStyle = .partialCurl
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destVC)
        present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Working like a charm so far. When the detail VC appears everything's great, the tableView works perfectly, the leftBarButtonItem dismisses the detailVC as it should, but whenever I press anywhere on the upper side of the screen the detail view somehow automatically dismisses itself, which I don't want. I'm gonna leave a link to an image to see exactly what part of the screen automatically enables the dismiss function:
http://prntscr.com/kaibxg
I've been struggling with this and I didn't find any solution. I don't know why this is happening. When I use the pushViewController function, the detail VC is all right and is not popping itself out, but the thing is I really need to use the .partialCurl transition animation. I tried to find a way to somehow use .partialCurl when pushing the VC but I didn't find anything about that. Any help, answer, question is more than welcomed and appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you might need to check the size of the `UIBarButtomItem` by the way don't write too much so more people would read your question

Comment: This is the code that I'm using, so no miss written frame navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backTapped))
The thing is that by even not having the button the detail VC is self dismissing and I really haven't found anyone with this problem. Ok, sorry for the long post...

Comment: Are using touchs began in your code?

Comment: I'm not using any kind of touch specific events/functions...

Comment: Can you just try to keep a reference to the navigation controller before presenting it ?

Comment: I'm gonna leave an answer since others might want to look up into this question/answer. I've talked to a good friend who has lot of years of experience in both ios and android. Please check the answer. Thanks guys

Comment: So, for unknown reasons I cannot post an answer...great. I'm gonna talk to help center and figure this out and I will post the answer to this one way or another...  
EDIT: Maybe in a screenshot hmmm? Here is the answer:  
http://prntscr.com/kav95k  
Hope this will help you guys. Thank you all

Comment: @CZ54 Sorry for the late reply...tried that...same behaviour...